# How do make sure there is no conflict of "v7 appcompat or support" of my library when any application uses my library?

Tags: android-appcompat, android-library

I have a android library with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` dependency in the gradle.

Say any applicaion with different version `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0`is in the build.gradle of that application uses my library.

Below are the list of questions I have doubt.

1. which version does the android take? Lower one or Higher one? How do i see it?
2. Won't there be any conflict if i use different version like 24 or 25 and above or same?
3. How do i make sure there is no conflict of v7 appcompat when any app uses my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. which version does the android take? Lower one or Higher one? How do i see it?

Gradle uses the higher one.
You can use the command `gradlew dependencies` to check the dependencies tree.

> 2. Won't there be any conflict if i use different version like 24 or 25 and above or same?
> 3. How do i make sure there is no conflict of v7 appcompat when any app uses my library?

In general the best way to maintain a library and to avoid the conflicts is to update the library always with the latest support libraries.

> What if the compiledSDK of application is 23 with appcompat-v7:23.3.0 and and that of the library is 24 with appcompat-v7:24+. Which all support libraries does the android take?

If your library uses support libraries v24, the library and the app will require to be compiled with the same level = 24.

Comment: Cleared few doubts. Here is one more, what if the compiledSDK of application is 23 with appcompat-v7:23.3.0 and and that of the library is 24 with appcompat-v7:24+.                                                                         Which all support libraries does the android take? if it takes appcompat-v7:24+, does it mean that it doesn't matter what compiledSDK is the application using?                                                                                         Or will the compiledSDK change itself for application to 24 since the library has compiledSDK of 24?